# Parallelization in CUDA, assigning threads to each column

Tags: arrays, cuda

Say I have a 1D array converted from a MxN 2D matrix, and I want to parallelize each column and do some operations. How do I assign a thread to each column?

For example, if I have a 3x3 matrix:

```
1  2  3

4  5  6

7  8  9
```

And I want to add each number in the column depending on the column # (so 1st column will add 1, 2nd will add 2....), it then becomes:

```
1+1   2+1   3+1

4+2   5+2   6+2

7+3   8+3   9+3
```

How do I do this in CUDA?  I know how to assign threads to all the elements in the array but I don't know how to assign thread to each column. So, what I want is to send each column (1 , 2  ,3 )  ( 4 , 5 ,6 ) (7 , 8 ,9) and do the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example you are adding numbers based on the row. Still, you know the row/column length of the matrix (you know it's MxN). What you could do is something like:

```
__global__ void MyAddingKernel(int* matrix, int M, int N)
{

    int gid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    //Let's add the row number to each element
    matrix[ gid ] += gid % M;
    //Let's add the column number to each element
    matrix[ gid ] += gid % N;

}
```

If you wanted to add a different number, you could do something like:

```
matrix[ gid ] += my_col_number_function(gid%N);
```

Comment: Oh Thanks for the reply, but what if I want to shift each element from the right to the left in each row instead of adding? So, in my example,  the first row ( 1 2 3 ) would become (2 3 3 ) [keeping the last element the same] , ( 4 5 6 ) becomes ( 5 6 6 ) and ( 7 8 9 ) becomes ( 8 9 9)  ? Is it possible do it like the addition operation you showed ? thanks!

Comment: In this case something like
`matrix[ gid ] = (gid % N) ? matrix[gid + 1] : matrix[gid];`
Might work.

Comment: modulo operator is a costly operation on the gpu, try to avoid it!

Answer (score 1):

Use a better grid layout to avoid those modulo operations.

Use the unique block index for the rows which is 64-bit range on latest Cuda.

Let the threads iterate in a loop over all elements and add the unique thread index!

Tiling input data is a general approach if calculated data is uniquely across a block (rows), especially for more complex calculations.

```
/*
 * @param tileCount 
 */
__global__ void addRowNumberToCells(int* inOutMat_g, 
    const unsigned long long int inColumnCount_s, 
    const int inTileCount_s)
{

    //get unique block index
    const unsigned long long int blockId = blockIdx.x //1D
        + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x //2D
        + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; //3D

    /* 
     * check column ranges in case kernel is called 
     * with more blocks then columns 
     * (since its block wide following syncthreads are safe)
     */
    if(blockId >= inColumnCount_s)
        return;

    //get unique thread index
    const unsigned long long int threadId = blockId * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 

    /*
     * calculate unique and 1 blockId
     * maybe shared memory is overhead 
     * but it shows concept if calculation is more complex
     */
    __shared__ unsigned long long int blockIdAnd1_s;
    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        blockIdAnd1_s = blockId + 1;
    __sycnthreads();


    unsigned long long int idx;

    //loop over tiles
    for(int i = 0; i < inTileCount_s)
    {
        //calculate new offset for sequence thread writes
        idx = i * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        //check new index range in case column count is no multiple of blockDim.x
        if(idx >= inColumnCount_s)
            break;
        inOutMat_g[idx] = blockIdAnd1_s;
    }

}
```

**Example Cuda 2.0:**

mat[131000][1000]

Necessary blockCount = 131000 / 65535 = 2 for blockDim.y rounded up!

inTileCount_s = 1000 / 192 = 6 rounded up!

(192 Threads per Block = 100 occupancy on Cuda 2.0)

<<(65535, 2, 1), (192, 1, 1)>>addRowNumberToCells(mat, 1000, 6)