# Very poor memory access performance with CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm very new to CUDA, and trying to write a test program.
I'm running the application on GeForce GT 520 card, and get VERY poor performance.

The application is used to process some image, with each row being handled by a separate thread.
Below is a simplified version of the application. Please note that in the real application, all constants are actually variables, provided be the caller.

When running the code below, it takes **more than 20 seconds** to complete the execution.

But as opposed to using ***malloc/free***, when `l_SrcIntegral` is defined as a local array (as it appears in the commented line), it takes **less than 1 second** to complete the execution.

Since the actual size of the array is dynamic (and not 1700), this local array can't be used in the real application.

Any advice how to improve the performance of this rather simple code would be appreciated.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define d_MaxParallelRows 320
#define d_MinTreatedRow   5
#define d_MaxTreatedRow   915
#define d_RowsResolution  1
#define k_ThreadsPerBlock 64

__global__ void myKernel(int Xi_FirstTreatedRow)
{
  int l_ThreadIndex = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (l_ThreadIndex >= d_MaxParallelRows)
    return;
  int l_Row = Xi_FirstTreatedRow + (l_ThreadIndex * d_RowsResolution);
  if (l_Row <= d_MaxTreatedRow) {

    //float l_SrcIntegral[1700];
    float* l_SrcIntegral = (float*)malloc(1700 * sizeof(float));

    for (int x=185; x<1407; x++) {
      for (int i=0; i<1700; i++)
        l_SrcIntegral[i] = i;
    }

    free(l_SrcIntegral);
  }
}

int main()
{
  cudaError_t cudaStatus;

  cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);

  int l_ThreadsPerBlock = k_ThreadsPerBlock;
  int l_BlocksPerGrid = (d_MaxParallelRows + l_ThreadsPerBlock - 1) / l_ThreadsPerBlock;

  int l_FirstRow = d_MinTreatedRow;
  while (l_FirstRow <= d_MaxTreatedRow) {
    printf("CUDA: FirstRow=%d\n", l_FirstRow);
    fflush(stdout);

    myKernel<<<l_BlocksPerGrid, l_ThreadsPerBlock>>>(l_FirstRow);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    l_FirstRow += (d_MaxParallelRows * d_RowsResolution);
  }

  printf("CUDA: Done\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you define `l_SrcIntegral` as a local memory array, compiler optimisation will eliminate the whole kernel and you will wind up running an empty stub. The CUDA compiler(s) are very aggressive at removing dead code that doesn't contribute to a global memory write. So I wouldn't read much into the difference in performance between the two cases.

Comment: @talonmies, what you say is that I need to enhance my sample, such that the memory writes won't be optimized away? I'll try doing that. Thanks.

Comment: @talonmies, foget about the local memory array. Any tips of how making the code above run much faster than the 20+ seconds it runs now?

Comment: What do you actually want to compute?

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

As @aland said, you will maybe even encounter worse performance calculating just one row in each kernel call.

You have to think about processing the whole input, just to theoretically use the power of the massive parallel processing.

Why start multiple kernels with just 320 threads just to calculate one row?
How about using as many blocks you have rows and let the threads per block process one row.

(320 threads per block is not a good choice, check out how to reach better occupancy)

**2.**

If your fast resources as registers and shared memory are not enough, you have to use a tile apporach which is one of the basics using GPGPU programming.

Separate the input data into tiles of equal size and process them in a loop in your thread.

Here I posted an example of such a tile approach:

[Parallelization in CUDA, assigning threads to each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10340296/parallelization-in-cuda-assigning-threads-to-each-column/10343277#10343277)

Be aware of range checks in that tile approach!

**Example to give you the idea:**

Calculate the sum of all elements in a column vector in an arbitrary sized matrix.

Each block processes one column and the threads of that block store in a tile loop their elements in a shared memory array. When finished they calculate the sum using parallel reduction, just to start the next iteration.
At the end each block calculated the sum of its vector.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use dynamic array sizes using shared memory. Just pass a third argument in the `<<<...>>>` of the kernel call. That'd be the size of your shared memory per block.

Once you're there, just bring all relevant data into your shared array (you should still try to keep coalesced accesses) bringing one or several (if it's relevant to keep coalesced accesses) elements per thread. Sync threads after it's been brought (only if you need to stop race conditions, to make sure the whole array is in shared memory before any computation is done) and you're good to go.

Also: you should tessellate using blocks and threads, not loops. I understand that's just an example using a local array, but still, it could be done tessellating through blocks/threads and not nested for loops (which are VERY bad for performance!) I hope you're running your sample code using just 1 block and 1 thread, otherwise it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is a VERY simplified version of my application. The real code consists of various functions, some of them contain loops. When I stripped down all these functions, I was left with the loops seen above.

Comment: Regarding the shared memory usage, it seems that I can't allocate a shared memory large enough for my needs. The kernel activation fails when I specify a shared memory size which is adequate for the storage required by all the threads.

Comment: The application processes the image one row at a time, and it was adjusted to perform parallel processing, by creating 320 threads, each of them handling a single row. So the main function starts 320 threads at a time, until all rows of the image are handled.

Comment: @MarkM Running 320 threads on GPU is unlikely to produce any speedup. Try to rewrite your algorithm so each thread handles lesser amount of data, but htere are more threads. Right now, with such a heavy threads, it seems barely suitable for GPGPU architecture.